# Iterate over N arrays in a certain order

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I want to iterate over n arrays in a certain way. 
The number of arrays is undefined.

This would be an example:

this entry:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G']]
```

This output should be printed:

```
[ADF, ADG, AEF, AEG, BDF, BDG, BEF, BEG, CDF, CDG, CEF, CEG]
```

To be more specific with the way to order them:

```
ADF - ADG - AEF - AEG - BDF - BDG - BEF - BEG - CDF - CDG - CEF - CEG
111   112   121   122   211   212   221   222   311   312   321   322
```

Where the numbers are the index of each letter in the previous arrays.

another example:

Input:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H']]
```

Output:

```
ADF - ADG - ADH - AEF - AEG - AEH - BDF - BDG - BDH - BEF - BEG - BEH - CDF - CDG - CDH - CEF - CEG - CEH 
111   112   113   121   122   123   211   212   213   221   222   223   311   312   313   321   322   323
```

Is there a way to make a recursive function to obtain that order? I tried to find a pattern with the length of each array, but I could not find this solution. I'm trying to do it in python

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: i'm trying to do it in python

Comment: Hi there :) this question is much easier if the number of arrays **is** defined beforehand. Perhaps it would be helpful to try implementing a solution for a fixed number of arrays (e.g. 3), since it could give you insight into what code is *repeated* and can be *generalized* to accept any number of arrays :)

Comment: With such a solution to the simpler problem, it would also be easy to return to Stack Overflow to ask for help extending it to work with any number of arrays :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is just a product :

```
from itertools import product
[''.join(x) for x in product(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'])]
# ['ADF', 'ADG', 'AEF', 'AEG', 'BDF', 'BDG', 'BEF', 'BEG', 'CDF', 'CDG', 'CEF', 'CEG']
```

The recursive way:

```
def prod (sets):
    if not sets : return ['']
    res=[]
    for x in sets[0]:
        for y in prod(sets[1:]):
            res.append (x+y)
    return res
```

Comment: And since the OP already as the list of lists, it's just, for example,  `product(*x)` rather than `product(x[0], x[1], x[2])`.

Comment: It's just what I was looking for. I was making it more complicated than it really was. Many thanks.